# How to stop view pager from swiping ,when I'm just swiping the list view in a fragment of a tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to disable tab layout swipe between the fragments when I'm just swiping the individual list in a list view to show the delete button in one of my fragments.

when i swipe the list i only want the list to show the slide motion but not the whole view pager

Comment: You mean swiping a element in a listview to dismiss?

Comment: yes and swiping a element in list view also swaps fragment (view pager)

Comment: Tablayout and swipe to dismiss by recyclerview are in conflict because they give a callback for the same movement. I would recommend to disable swipe behavior on the tablayout.

Comment: Because you can still navigate by the tags

Comment: can i make it possible only with view pager and fragments without using tablayout.

Comment: Depends on what your target behavior should look like

Comment: want to swipe between the 3 fragments and one of the fragment contains a swappable list view and upon swiping list element ,i don't want the page to be swiped(only the list element should) ,otherwise it should swipe.

Comment: If its a recyclerview you can easily set the swipe up or down to dismiss. then the conflict is solved

Comment: Use `Non-Swipable` `ViewPager` for it.